# Parallel HttpWebRequests with Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a class "Image" with three properties: Url, Id, Content.
I have a list of 10 such images.
This is a silverlight app.

I want to create a method:

```
IObservable<Image> DownloadImages(List<Image> imagesToDownload)
{
     //start downloading all images in imagesToDownload
     //OnImageDownloaded: 
                          image.Content = webResponse.Content
                          yield image

}
```

This method starts downloading all 10 images in parallel.
Then, when each downloads completes, it sets the Image.Content to the WebResponse.Content of that download.

The result should be an IObservable stream with each downloaded image.

I'm a beginner in RX, and I think what I want can be achieved with ForkJoin, but that's in an experimental release of reactive extensions dll which I don't want to use.

Also I really don't like download counting on callbacks to detect that all images have been downloaded and then call onCompleted().

Doesn't seem to be in the Rx spirit to me.

Also I post what solution I've coded so far, though I don't like my solution because its long/ugly and uses counters.

```
     return Observable.Create((IObserver<Attachment> observer) =>
         {
             int downloadCount = attachmentsToBeDownloaded.Count;
                foreach (var attachment in attachmentsToBeDownloaded)
                        {
                            Action<Attachment> action = attachmentDDD =>
                            this.BeginDownloadAttachment2(attachment).Subscribe(imageDownloadWebResponse =>
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        using (Stream stream = imageDownloadWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
                                        {
                                            attachment.FileContent = stream.ReadToEnd();
                                        } 
                                        observer.OnNext(attachmentDDD);

                                        lock (downloadCountLocker)
                                        {
                                            downloadCount--;
                                            if (downloadCount == 0)
                                            {
                                                observer.OnCompleted();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        observer.OnError(ex);
                                    }
                                });
                            action.Invoke(attachment);
                        }

                        return () => { }; //do nothing when subscriber disposes subscription
                    });
            }
```

Ok, I did manage it to make it work in the end based on Jim's answer.

```
    var obs = from image in attachmentsToBeDownloaded.ToObservable()
               from webResponse in this.BeginDownloadAttachment2(image).ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
               from responseStream in Observable.Using(webResponse.GetResponseStream, Observable.Return)
               let newImage = setAttachmentValue(image, responseStream.ReadToEnd())
               select newImage;
```

where setAttachmentValue just takes does `image.Content = bytes; return image;

BeginDownloadAttachment2 code:

```
        private IObservable<WebResponse> BeginDownloadAttachment2(Attachment attachment)
    {
        Uri requestUri = new Uri(this.DownloadLinkBaseUrl + attachment.Id.ToString();
        WebRequest imageDownloadWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        IObservable<WebResponse> imageDownloadObservable = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(imageDownloadWebRequest.BeginGetResponse, imageDownloadWebRequest.EndGetResponse)();

        return imageDownloadObservable;
    }
```

Comment: Glad to help. I have to say that the solution looks much easier to maintain than what you started with.

Comment: Good use of .Let. Very nice solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about we simplify this a bit. Take your image list and convert it to an observable. Next, consider using the Observable.FromAsyncPattern to manage the service requests. Finally use SelectMany to coordinate the request with the response. I'm making some assumptions on how you are getting the file streams here. Essentially if you can pass in the BeginInvoke/EndInvoke delegates into FromAsyncPattern for your service request you are good.

```
var svcObs = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<Stream>(this.BeginDownloadAttachment2, This.EndDownloadAttchment2);

var obs = from image in imagesToDownload.ToObservable()
          from responseStream in svcObs(image)
          .ObserveOnDispatcher()
          .Do(response => image.FileContent = response.ReadToEnd())
          select image;
return obs;
```

Comment: Thank you Jim. Its almost good. The single problem I'm having is that BeginDownloadAttachment2 returns an IObservable<WebResponse>. I tried converting the code to:  ...Do(response => Observable.Using(response.GetResponseStream, stream => image.FileContent = stream.ReadToEnd())) but I get some error: type arguments cannot be inferred from usage.

Comment: Actually I think I've got it: ...Do(response => Observable.Using(response.GetResponseStream, stream => Observable.Return(stream.ReadToEnd())).Do( bytes => image.Value.FileContent = bytes)). Will test and see if it works.

Comment: I was referring to my last solution from my last comment. Wasn't working because those "Do" operators were setting the bytes after my subscriber was reading the image. I couldn't use your solution as it was because this.BeginDownloadAttachment2 returns an IObservable<WebResponse>. But anyway I've got it in the end modifying your solution a bit. You can see it at the bottom of the question. Thanks a lot for your help.